# Object doesn't support #inspect in rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I migrated my application from rails 2.3.11 to rails 3.2.1

My models

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaign_reports
end


class CampaignReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

In the console, I got the output but when I do

```
c = Campaign.first
c.campaign_reports
```

I get

> (Object doesn't support #inspect)

Comment: Please add stack trace here..

Comment: thx lucapette for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

what I found is

```
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:68: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:69: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:70: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
```